# finding an embed created by a bot (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This might be a little bit complicated...

I have made on my server a report system, where if a user reacts with an "❗", this message gets reported in a channel only the owner sees. This is my code so far:

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (messageReaction, user) => {
    const msg = messageReaction.message;
    if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "❗") {
        if (messageReaction.count > 1) {
            // code missing here
        } else {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#ff9e00")
            .setDescription("§ Report")
            .setFooter(`${msg.member.user.tag}`, msg.member.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp()
            .addFields(
                {name: "Message", value: `[${msg.cleanContent}](${msg.url})`, inline: false},
                {name: "Amount", value: messageReaction.count, inline: true},
                {name: "Channel", value: `${msg.channel.name}`, inline: true});

            msg.member.guild.channels.cache.get(config.channels.report).send((embed));
        }
    };
});
```

so, everytime someone reports a message, and he was the first one reporting it, my bot will send a new bot, but I want now if a reaction is not the first, I want that the bot edits the according embed, and increases/updates the `messageReaction.count`.
Anyone an idea how I find the initial message without having a database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to listen to raw events https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/coding-guides/raw-events.md

Comment: Please don't put two questions in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the code to keep a collection of message IDs from reports that have been sent.

When a report needs to be edited, its ID is fetched from the collection and used to get the actual message, then a new embed is then created from the old embed with the second field incremented. Finally, the message is edited with the new embed containing the incremented field.

```js
client.on("messageReactionAdd", async (messageReaction, user) => {
    const msg = messageReaction.message;
    if (messageReaction.emoji.name == "❗") {
        if (messageReaction.count > 1) {
            const message = (await msg.guild.channels.cache.get(config.channels.report).messages.fetch()).find(message => message.embeds[0].fields[3].value === msg.id);

            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(message.embeds[0])
            .spliceFields(1, 1, {name: "Amount", value: messageReaction.count, inline: true});

            message.edit(embed);
        } else {
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#ff9e00")
            .setDescription("§ Report")
            .setFooter(`${msg.member.user.tag}`, msg.member.user.displayAvatarURL())
            .setTimestamp()
            .addFields(
                {name: "Message", value: `[${msg.cleanContent}](${msg.url})`, inline: false},
                {name: "Amount", value: messageReaction.count, inline: true},
                {name: "Channel", value: `${msg.channel.name}`, inline: true},
                {name: "Message ID", value: msg.id, inline: false});

            msg.guild.channels.cache.get(config.channels.report).send(embed);
        }
    };
});
```

Here is some extra code if you want to edit reports when the original message gets deleted:

```js
client.on("messageDelete", async (msg) => {
    const message = (await msg.guild.channels.cache.get(config.channels.report).messages.fetch()).find(message => message.embeds[0].fields[3].value === msg.id);

    if (message) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(message.embeds[0])
        .spliceFields(0, 1, {name: "Message", value: `[${msg.cleanContent}](*deleted*)`, inline: false})
        .spliceFields(3, 1, {name: "Message ID", value: '*deleted*', inline: false})
        .setDescription("§ Report\n**The user deleted their message, but here is its content.**");

        message.edit(embed);
    }
});
```

Comment: hey thank you very much! But does this also work if the bots gets relaunched, shouldn't be the report-collection be then empty again?

Comment: also, `message.embeds[0]` seems not to work, where does this array "embeds" come from, also my cmd is saying `cannot ready property "embeds" of undefined`, so the message is also not really gotten

Comment: okay so I found out, that the `const message = msg.channel.messages.cache.get(reports.get(msg.id));` is not working, I guess it cant get the message object of the embed

Comment: okay I found your issue, you are searching for the embed in the msg.channel, but my report is send in a report channel, I modified it, but now it only works without the bot restarting, so still I need a database... thank you anyway!

Comment: I have modified my code as described in my comment above.

Comment: yes I saw it, but I dont want to have a database as said in my question ;)

Comment: I have modified the code to store the original message's ID in the report embed, so that the reports can be matched up with the original messages without having to store anything in a database.

Comment: nice it seem's to work, but only without restarting my bot. If I restart it, it cant find the message `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'embeds' of undefined`, it's in the line of `const message = msg.guild...`

Comment: the thing is, that my report channel is not in the cache after a restart

Comment: FINALLY! THANK YOU VERY MUCH